# Select certain elements from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to extract user IDs from a form serialized string, here is what I have so far.

Take

`var dataString = "viewUsers_length=10&id%5B%5D=8163&id%5B%5D=8188&id%5B%5D=8141"`

as the example string.

I split it into an array like this

```
var arrStr = dataString.split(/[=&]/);
```

which results in an array

```
[0]viewUsers_length
[1]10
[2]id%5B%5D
[3]8163
[4]id%5B%5D
[5]8188
[6]id%5B%5D
[7]8141
```

But I only want the ids (8163, 8188, 8141)

in reality this string could contain thousands of ids in this format. I've spent some time googling so far and haven't found anything that I think will work.

Comment: quick and dirty fix: from the second array case push on a new array each elem which have odd index. But parsing get parms could get done on fancier way

Comment: This might be *overkill*, but I hacked up a function to parse query strings a while ago.  If you pass your `dataString` to my `parseQuery` method, you'll get an object, then you can just get the `id` property.  https://gist.github.com/NTICompass/3528917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to address this. The first way, that I would use, would be to match the ID's with regex.

```
var ids = dataString.match(/id%5B%5D=[0-9]+/g);
```

Which would result in

```
["id%5B%5D=8163", "id%5B%5D=8188", "id%5B%5D=8141"]
```

So now we have the values, but we only want the numeric parts of it. So let's use `map` to remove the rest

```
ids = ids.map(function (id) {
    return id.replace('id%5B%5D=', '');
});
```

The other way would just be to filter on the array you already built, but you can see that you have the 10 in the second index, which would come back as a false positive, so I think this would provide a cleaner dataset

Comment: thank you, this is the solution I went with and it seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately because the parameter names for the ids are all the same, normal methods of parsing query strings might not be viable. So, this might be a job for regular expressions!

```js
var dataString = "viewUsers_length=10&id%5B%5D=8163&id%5B%5D=8188&id%5B%5D=8141";

var regex = /&id%5B%5D=(\d+)/g;
var match;
var matches = [];
while (match = regex.exec(dataString)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
  }

console.log(matches)
var list = matches.join(', ');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = list;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array.

There are native JavaScript ways using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var dataString = "viewUsers_length=10&id%5B%5D=8163&id%5B%5D=8188&id%5B%5D=8141"
var arrStr = dataString.split(/[=&]/);

var tester = /\d{4}/;

arrStr.filter(function (item) {
    return tester.test(item);
});

/*
viewUsers_length
10
id%5B%5D
8163                -Match
id%5B%5D
8188                -Match
id%5B%5D
8141                -Match
*/
```

As well as jQuery ways using [`$().filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, after some reading I under .filter() better now.

Answer (score 0):

I would split on the "&" characters, then map a function to remove everything before the "=", and finally filter to remove elements that aren't id elements. My substring function is a bit crude, and could be improved (or replaced with regex) with more knowledge of the possible values.

```
dataString
  .split("&")
  .map(function(elt){return elt.startsWith("id") ? elt.substring(9,13) : ""})
  .filter(function(elt){return elt != ""})
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. i'm sure i will use .map in future

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dataString = "viewUsers_length=10&id%5B%5D=8163&id%5B%5D=8188&id%5B%5D=8141";
var myRegexp = /id%5B%5D=([0-9]+)/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(dataString);
while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(ddd);
}
```

outputs

```
8163
8188
8141
```